# How to get a Class<?> instance from a File instance without resorting to strings

Tags: java

**Situation**

A directory full of '.class' files, in appropriate subdirectories according to their class path.

**Desire**

Get a Class instance for each of those '.class' files, *without* resorting to string manipulation to get 'fully qualified class names' for each of the files.

**Research**

I've seen plenty of ways to get a Class instance from a string.

What I'd like to do is avoid strings altogether, and just do something like this:

```
/**
 * Foo Description Here
 *
 * @parameter file A File instance referring to a '.class' file.
 */
public Class<?> Foo(File file) {
    ...
    return someClassLoader.loadClass(file);
}
```

The "file" argument already refers to a '.class' file.  I already know that I could massage the path from the 'file' argument, and get to something that is recognizably a fully qualified class name.  I want to avoid all that messing about with strings if I can.

I've already seen the following:

- [How can get an instance from .class file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21258032/1608079)

That's exactly what I don't want to do.  And I've seen:

- [How to get an instance of java.lang.Class from a .class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10622637/1608079)

Where the second answer comes close, but leaves open the question of how you get the fully qualified name of the class for the last step.  You still have to either mess around with strings, or just arbitrarily name them as you define them.

After munching around in the JavaDocs, StackOverflow, et.al., I am beginning to wonder if there's any way to do this.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the aversion to strings is.  If it works, why avoid it?

Comment: I suppose because it seems silly to already have a handle on the '.class' file, only to have to go through shenanigans like peeling the classpath directory off the beginning, and the '.class' off the end, then replace all the '/' with '.' to end up with a full qualified class path.  That's a lot of extra work to get your hands on something that you've already got a direct reference to.  I was hoping that there was a class loader that already accepted 'File' instances, and I just wasn't seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) for this.
From its documentation:

```
ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
InputStream ins = an input stream for reading a class file;
CtClass cc = cp.makeClass(ins);
```

and then convert to class with:

```
Class clazz = cc.toClass();
```

Comment: Cool!  I'll look this over and get back to you.  First blush is that it's overkill, but it should do the job.

Comment: If you can't use a regular class loader (which requires you to know the class name), you need to bring in the big guns.

Comment: It would indeed do the job, but the team lead shot it down.  <sigh>  I'll be doing the string manipulation anyway.  Thanks for your help!